# Remaining item positions in ListView is incorrect after deleting items

Tags: android, listview, view, position

I'm having trouble with getting the correct items after deleting an item in my ListView.
The position should fit to the index of the item in an ArrayList, but after deleting an item in the ListView, the positions are incorrect (and might even give an indexoutofbounds exception.

I bet it has something to do with the Views position, but I just can't find the error.

I have this ListActivity class with an inner BaseAdapter class:

```
    public class MSMobilMyStocksActivity extends ListActivity {
    static MyStocksCtr myStocksCtr;
    static ListView listview;



    static EfficientAdapter adap;
    boolean downloadSuccess;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mystockslist);
        mContext = this;
        listview = getListView();
        myStocksCtr = MyStocksCtr.getInstance(mContext);

        adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);

        setListAdapter(adap);
        if (isOnline())
            new InsertDataTask().execute();
        else {
            startTimer();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Du har ingen internetforbindelse", 1000)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    public static boolean updateData() {
        return myStocksCtr.downloadJson();
    }

    private class InsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                listview.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        // can use UI thread here
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (isOnline()) {
                if (downloadSuccess) {
                    try {
                        if (myStocksCtr.getArray().size() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ingen data hentet", 2000)
                                    .show();
                        } else if (myStocksCtr.getArray().size() == 1
                                && myStocksCtr.getArray().get(0)
                                        .getString("FH_FULLNAME").equals("-")) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ingen data hentet", 2000)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "JSONException", 2000).show();
                    }
                }
            } else
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Du har ingen internetforbindelse",
                        1000).show();
            startTimer();
            try {
                listview.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            downloadSuccess = false;
            if (isOnline()) {
                try {
                    if (updateData())
                        downloadSuccess = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fejl under download af data",
                            2000).show();
                    downloadSuccess = false;
                }
            } else
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Du har ingen internetforbindelse",
                        1000).show();

            return null;

        }
    }

    }

    public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context context;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.stockName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.stockName1);
                holder.stockPrice = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.stockValue1);
                holder.stockChange = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.stockChange1);
                holder.stockPctChange = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.stockPctChange1);

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try {
                            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MSStockDetailActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putInt("position", position); //Your id
                            b.putBoolean("isMyStocks", true);
                            i.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
                            mContext.startActivity(i);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "OnClick error ", 2000)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

                        final CharSequence[] items = {
                                "See stock details",
                                "Delete the stock \"" + holder.stockName.getText()
                                        + "\" from the list", "Cancel" };

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                mContext);
                        builder.setTitle("Configure list");
                        builder.setItems(items,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int item) {
                                        if (item == 1) {
                                            myStocksCtr.removeStock(holder.ric);
                                            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        } else if (item == 2) {
                                        }
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, items[item],
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            try {
                String result = myStocksCtr.getArray().get(position)
                        .getString("FH_FULLNAME");
                holder.stockName.setText(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String result = myStocksCtr.getArray().get(position)
                        .getString("FH_RIC");
                holder.ric = result;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // + String.valueOf(position));
            try {
                String result = myStocksCtr.getArray().get(position)
                        .getString("FH_PRC");
                if (String.valueOf(result.charAt(result.length() - 2)).equals(
                        ".")) {
                    result += "0";
                }
                ;
                holder.stockPrice.setText(result);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.position = position;

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            String ric;
            TextView stockName;
            TextView stockPrice;
            TextView stockPctChange;
            TextView stockChange;
            int position;

        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myStocksCtr.getArray().size();
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
            return myStocksCtr.getArray().get(position);
        }

    }
```

This is some of the things in my stocks controller (where the array is):

```
public class MyStocksCtr {

private static MyStocksCtr INSTANCE = null;

ArrayList<String> myStocksArray;
JSONCtr jsonCtr;
static Context mContext;
boolean isRunning = false;
ArrayList<JSONObject> myArray;

MyStocksCtr(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    jsonCtr = new JSONCtr(mContext);
    myStocksArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    myArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    }
}

public static MyStocksCtr getInstance(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
          INSTANCE = new MyStocksCtr(mContext);
       }
       return INSTANCE;
}

public ArrayList<JSONObject> getArray() {
    return myArray;
}

public boolean downloadJson() {
    if (!myStocksArray.isEmpty()) {
        String myStocksString = "";
        for (String s : myStocksArray)
            myStocksString += (s + "%2C");
        myStocksString = myStocksString.substring(0,
                myStocksString.length() - 3);
        jsonCtr.getJSON(preStocksUrl + myStocksString + postStocksUrl);
        myArray.clear();
        myArray.addAll(jsonCtr.getArray());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


public void removeStock(String newStock) {
    JSONObject toRemove = null;

    for (JSONObject obj : myArray) {
        try {
            if (obj.getString("FH_RIC").equals(newStock)) {
                toRemove = obj;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Kunne ikke fjerne objekt", 1000)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    if (toRemove != null){
        myStocksArray.remove(newStock);
    jsonCtr.removeRic(toRemove);
    myArray = jsonCtr.getArray();
    saveMyStocks();
}
    }

    }
```

In my jsonCtr I remove and get the array:

```
public ArrayList<JSONObject> getArray() {
    return rics1;
}

public void removeRic(Object o){
    rics1.remove(o);
}
```

When i have removed an object from the list, the list is updated, so the item is no longer there. But the positions of the views are all messed up, and some of them are outofbounds.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the position in GetView is final, but I'm not sure? And if that is the problem, how do I correct it?

Comment: still incomplete the code for listview please provide the listview implementation code here

Comment: Code is now edited.. I have added the whole ListActivity..

Comment: I completely forgot: Please post your logcat output (exception stack). That would help a lot for sure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I didn't looked at every detail of your code but i think you're missing to call `myAdaper`.[notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) after changing your array.

**Edit**

That*s really tough to look trough because it's a lot of code you post here. So here is what I got. I can't see what's going on in here (on stock remove) but there must be something wrong I think:

```
jsonCtr.removeRic(toRemove);
myArray = jsonCtr.getArray();
```

Please don't post the whole code of that too, try to reduce it to the actual problem. I wont check the whole code again...

Comment: Code is updated.. The notifyDataSetChanged() is used when changing in the array - but is it the right way??

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm quite new to this..
I've added the code that you're referring to..